# Can you put struct impl blocks in a different file?

Tags: struct, rust, project-structure

Say, for purposes of conjecture, that you have three files: `main.rs`, `struct.rs`, and `impl.rs`. Could you define a struct in `struct.rs`, put an `impl` there, put another `impl` in `impl.rs`, and then use both sets of `impl`s from `main.rs`? If so, how?

Project structure:

```
main.rs:
    use struct;
    use impl;

    main() {
        let foobar = struct::Struct::new(); // defined in struct.rs
        foobar.x();  // defined in impl.rs
    }

struct.rs:
    Define Struct, first impl

impl.rs:
    Second impl
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can provide implementations for your struct throughout the crate. You just can't provide impls for types from foreign crates. And you don't need to do anything special to make this work – just make sure the struct is visible in `main`. Of course you can't name your modules `struct` and `impl`, since these are reserved words.

Here's some example code:

```
fn main() {
    use struct_::A;
    A::foo();
    A::bar();
}

pub mod struct_ {
    pub struct A;

    impl A {
        pub fn foo() {}
    }
}

mod impl_ {
    impl crate::struct_::A {
        pub fn bar() {}
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=619e8aa35fe63106f37543105f142223))